# My mail icon is not showing anything

Tags: ios, mobile-mail

I was in the middle of writing an email and pasting a photo into the email when everything disappeared and all I have is a white screen. No choice of mailbox etc displaying. Have tried shutting down the iPad and restarting three times. Still no mail.

Comment: Did you try specifically killing the app? Double click Home & slide the app up off the screen.